# Custom Dimensions with gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I'm trying to get custom dimensions to work in Google Analytics using the 'new' gtag library. I've added a new custom dimension to the property in the GA administration section:

[image: Username image]

Next I've configured a mapping as per the ([specs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/custom-dims-mets)) by adding this snippet:

```
gtag('config', '<My GA tag here>', {
    'send_page_view': false,
    'custom_map': {
        'dimension1': 'my_username'
    }
});
```

Next when the user logs in I set the `my_username` property:

```
gtag('set', 'my_username', '<username of logged in user>');
```

And expect it to be pushed for every event:

```
gtag('event', 'login');
gtag('event', 'page_view', {'page_path': calculated_current_spa_location});
etc
```

Unfortunately, while the events show up in Analytics when setting the secondary dimension to *Username* none of the events seem to have the value.

I've also tried setting the property directly when registering the event:

```
gtag('event', 'page_view', {
    'page_path': calculated_current_spa_location,
    'my_username', '<username of logged in user>'
});
```

But to no avail :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: I did not, but my priorities shifted and I've let it rest, if you do figure it out though, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {
    'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'my_username'}
});
gtag('event', 'my_username_event', {'my_username': '<username of logged in user>'});
```

Should work fine and should give you Secondary dimension data.

Comment: Do we need to define the `event` (e.g. `'my_username_event'`) somewhere else first and foremost? If yes, may I know how and where to define it? Thanks!

Comment: No - the event can be any string you like

Comment: Will this 'my_username_event' end up in Google Analytics? And will this event result in a bounce rate of 0%? Do we have to use nonInteraction like the old analytics.js?

Comment: `gtag('config'` is also used to send page-view without event. It sould be possible somehow to send dimantions with a page view.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar issue. It was related to not re-sending the custom dimensions again in `custom_map` when tracking page views. You can view my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120557/gtag-not-sending-custom-dimensions-for-events/48189202#48189202) on how I solved the problem.

Comment: I will try this, but contrary to your example, I'm not resetting the config on every page view, I'm using a `set` command to set the value and an `event` command to send the page_view