# ga to gtag in custom dimension in combination with custom reports and virtual pageviews

Tags: google-analytics

In the past I used a Google Analytics Custom Report to track the amount of pageviews per author and number of pageviews per forum topic category which I had setup like this in Google Analytics (analytics.js):

[image: Custom report screenshot]

The code I used to push this data to Google Analytics was simple  `ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Name of Author');`

I've updated my Google Analytics javascript snippet to gtag but I can't seem to push the data in the same way.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxx"></script>
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxx',
            { 'anonymize_ip': true,
              'forceSSL': true,
              'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'author', 'dimension4': 'forum_name'}
            });
        gtag('event', 'author', {'event_category': 'Writers', 'event_label': 'Author Name'});
        gtag('event', 'forum_name', {'event_category': 'Forum category', 'event_label': 'Forum Category name'});
    </script>
```

At the moment I am getting the data as an event in Google Analytics. But the way the code works right now makes it much harder to analyse the data. In the past I could click on an authors name and see which pages got the most pageviews and for the forum category it was the same. I could dig in and see per category the urls that brought in the most visitors.

I think the difference between the two code snippets is that ga 'set' was sent as a virtual pageview where the net gtag 'event' is an event and not an virtual pageview. The question now is how to setup a similar custom report as I has previously or how to update the code snippet to get a similar result as in the past?

**Update**

This is the old version of Google Analytics and the code I've been using:

```
<script>
        (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
        })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX', 'auto');
        ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Author Name');
        ga('set', 'dimension4', 'Forum name');
        ga('require', 'ec');
        ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
        ga('set', 'forceSSL', true);
        ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Comment: Try to see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120557/gtag-not-sending-custom-dimensions-for-events/48189202#48189202

Comment: You are suggesting that adding page_path: path should add a virtual "pageview"? I'll give it a try and see what it does. Thank you!

Comment: Tested it for 24 hours and unfortunately that didn't seem to work.

Comment: How was the virtual pageview previously being sent? On page load, via an onclick, onsubmit . or some other method?

Comment: @BronwynV I've added the code snippet I've been using previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of testing I finally found the answer to my own question. The trick seems to be to add the dimensions in the config so they are send as a pageview.

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxxx"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxx',
    { 'anonymize_ip': true,
      'forceSSL': true,
      'dimension1': 'Author Name', 'dimension4': 'Forum category'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your analytics.js code, the set command sets the custom dimensions and their given value so that they persist and send with all/any hits within the page. The example code snippet that was being used for analytics.js, is sending the cd's along with the default pageview.

Try instead

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('set', {'dimension1':  'Author Name', 'dimension4': 'Forum name'});
  gtag('config', 'UA-xxxxx',
        { 'anonymize_ip': true,
          'forceSSL': true
        });
</script>
```

If you have any onclick or other events being sent within the page, or virtual pageviews being sent within the page, it will also send the above custom dimensions and their set values with those too.

After doing some testing custom_map doesnt appear to be necessary (however it may come into play with the new app+web properties and possibly where the gtag.js snippet is used for multiple products and custom parameters need to be mapped).
Not sure, however I found custom_map somewhat strange in it's behaviour when i did some testing with it.

Comment: I tried to add your new code snippet in the last 24 hours, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have helped.

Comment: Not sure why, as i tested the code before hand and had no issue with it working in a test environment.  I would create a flat table report and add in the Page dimension together with the cd1 and cd4, and make sure you change the date to include the current day and past 24hrs (keeping in mind GA defaults to previous day for reports). You'll have to include a dimension for the hits that the cds are being sent with or you wont get any data in the report for it.
Also are you able to share one of the urls to a page with the code installed on it?